# Is the gc_maxlifetime timer restarted every time the user sends a query to the server?

Tags: php

From the PHP documentation:

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which
>   data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up

But, **is the countdown timer associated to this variable restarted every time the user (with a session started) sends a query to the server?**